# Panem-HungerGames: Are there no other countries to stop these types of "games"

Tags: the-hunger-games

I'm reading the Hunger Games (now starting Mockingjay), and I have seen the movies (not the new one).

While I'm reading, I have a big question. Are there no other countries to avoid this type of games?
Because in the book says that Panem is EEUU in a future... Or that is what I understood.. So what about (for example) other nations like France, Italy, Spain, Mexico, Russia... to stop it?

Comment: As I understand it, Panem was founded by gathering together all of the survivors of global catastrophe in one place, to ensure survival of the human race and allow the rest of the Earth time to recover.

Comment: Are you asking why other countries/governments don't try to *stop* it, or whether there *are* other countries/governments?

Comment: Also , since when has america ever listened to what other countries want, if the united nations tells the US to do something specific involving our own daily lives, the US typically replies with an F U. I like to think of panem being a continuation of the US after some massive world war , that we most likely started anyway.

Comment: @phantom42 Probably I wrote bit confusing. I wanted to ask, why atoher governaments/countries doesn't anything to avoid that. (In case of exist these governament)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's nothing in any canon material which describes what happens to other nations of the world.

Panem is described as being in "what was once called North America", as far as I know all we have are fan theories.

- There is no rest of the world (it was wiped out)
- Other countries are as uninterested in Panem as the Capitol appears to be in them.

Unfortunately without any information from Suzanne Collins none are any more valid than any other.